# When Graphics3D renders a Polygon with non planar points, how does it triangulate to two separate polygons?

Tags: graphics3d, polygons

If we try to make a `Polygon` with nonplanar points, the documentation says

> Non-planar polygons are accepted in `Graphics3D` and are triangulated, but the result is not platform and view independent and may lead to surprising results.

The surprising result, I think, is that the result appears to be a 2D polygon from *almost* any viewpoint.  Here is one such `Polygon` from two different viewpoints,

```
pts = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, -1}};
Graphics3D@*Polygon /@ {pts, pts}
```

[image]

But it clearly is showing two polygons with three points each, and I wonder how it chooses those points.  The system has chosen two such polygons out of the possible four,

```
Graphics3D@*Polygon /@ Subsets[pts, {3}]
```

[image]

It's possible to see which were chosen by discretizing the region first and then extracting the polygons,

```
Polygon[pts] // DiscretizeRegion // MeshPrimitives[#, 2] &
(* {Polygon[{{0., 0., 1.}, {0., -1., 0.}, {1., 0., -1.}}], 
 Polygon[{{0., -1., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}, {0., 1., 0.}}]} *)
```

What brings this up is the fact that the system often uses non-planar polygons when creating 3D plots, and the subsequent attempts to turn these plots into boundary regions is somewhat hampered by these nonplanar polygons (with the obvious workaround of first discretizing the graphics and then extracting the polygons).

Is there some way of knowing how the polygons are triangulated?

Comment: Are you interested in quadrilaterals only?

Comment: @BlacKow Not at all. I just noticed that when I extracted polygons from certain 3D plots, many of them had 4 or 5 points which were *not quite* coplanar.  I just wonder why would MMA use such polygons, how does it deal with them?

Comment: Your `Polygon[pts] // DiscretizeRegion // MeshPrimitives[#, 2] &` gives tons of polygons even for 5 points. In case of 4 points it's always two triangles? If yes it's probably possible to reverse engineer how they are generated.

Comment: @BlacKow I actually haven't tested it on too many, but all I've looked at, four points goes to two triangles.  I'd be very happy with just understanding that, absolutely

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this code `pts = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {1, 0, -1}};
Graphics3D@*Polygon /@ {pts, pts}; 
Polygon[pts] // DiscretizeRegion // MeshPrimitives[#, 2] & // Length` already gives me 323 triangles. MMA 10.2 on Mac

Comment: Related: [(16168)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16168)