# how to color edges of a convex polygon,say a square, using interpolation with respect to the color in Mathematica

Tags: color, interpolation, polynomials

How do I color edges of a convex polygon, say a square, using interpolation with respect to the color (to form parametric polynomials) in Mathematica, so that the colors displayed on the 4 edges would vary linearly (say we use three colors)?

Comment: I want the paramter to vary from 0 to 1

Comment: [Mean value coordinates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89147) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`VertexColors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html):

```
coords = {{1, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {1, 4}}; 
colors = {Green, Red, Blue, Orange};
verticesandcolors = Transpose /@ 
  Partition[Transpose[Join[#, {#[[1]]}] & /@ {coords, colors}], 2, 1];
Graphics[{Thickness[.03], Line[#, VertexColors -> #2] & @@@ verticesandcolors, 
  FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon@coords}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can construct a [`BSplineFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html) from `coords` and use it with `ParametricPlot` with a custom `ColorFunction`:

```
bsF = BSplineFunction[coords, SplineDegree -> 1, SplineClosed -> True];
cF = Blend[Transpose[{Range[0, 1, 1/4], Join[colors, {colors[[1]]}]}], #] &;
ParametricPlot[bsF[u], {u, 0, 1}, Axes -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[{JoinForm["Round"], CapForm["Round"], Thickness[.05]}],  
  ColorFunction -> (cF[#3] &), Epilog -> {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[coords]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can the function "Manipulate"  be incorporated in a way that is consistent with the question described?

Comment: @ChonglinZhu, what would you like to control in `Manipulate`?  Colors, coordinates...?

Comment: the color and the parameter goes from 0 to 1, I saw my tutor did it