# How do I find the most populous cities in the world?

Tags: list-manipulation, curated-data, entity

I am attempting to plot the most populous cities on a world map.

Currently, I have the line of code:

```
numberofpeople = 
  Map[{#, Length[CityData[#, "Population"]]} &, CityData[All]];
```

which should give me the City name, and the population. However, when I type in the line of code

```
Reverse[SortBy[numberofpeople, Last]][[1 ;; 20]]
```

I am getting odd data, which is that the most populous cities have 1 person.

Could somebody debug my code, and answer any future questions I have on the matter?
Much appreciated.

EDIT: How do I plot these points on a World Map? Currently I have

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], , CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"]} & /@ 
  CountryData[]]
```

but I have no idea what goes between the points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave out `Length` in `Length[CityData[#, "Population"]]`, and delete cases of `Missing` data:

```
numberofpeople = Map[{#, CityData[#, "Population"]} &, CityData[All]];

Reverse[SortBy[DeleteCases[numberofpeople, {_, _Missing}], Last]] ~Take~ 20 // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have one more question: how do I plot these points on a world map? My edit should have the information required for assistance.

Comment: @user9876 You're welcome.  Rather than extending your question please consider posting a new one; also, I don't understand what you want to do with the "world map" -- have you seen [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3646/121)?

Comment: I figured that since my new question is related to this one, I would just have an add-on to this one, instead of filling up the site with another question. I will make a new question regarding this topic.

Answer (score 2):

I was gonna post this as a comment but it'll be too long. As Mr. Wizard has shown you how to obtain the most popluar cities, here is how to plot them:

```
 Graphics[{{White, EdgeForm[Black],  CountryData[#, "FullPolygon"] & /@ CountryData[]}, 
{PointSize[Large], Red,    Tooltip[Point[Reverse[CityData[#, "Coordinates"]]], 
          CityData[#, "Name"]] & /@ largeCities}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here, `largeCities` are the names of the cities without their populations. So you can do something like

```
largeCities = Take[SortBy[numberofpeople, Last] // Reverse, 20][[All, 1]]
```

Comment: FWIW the OP already asked this as a [new question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34458/121), which was subsequently marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

`EntityClass` was introduced in July 2014. So here is my belated attempt.

```
popList = 
 EntityList[EntityClass["City", {"Population" -> TakeLargest[50]}]]
```

[image]

---

For slightly better presentation:

```
popCitiesTable = {#["Name"], #["Country"]["Name"], 
     ImageResize[#["Country"]["Flag"], {40, 25}], #["Population"]} & /@
    popList;
Grid[Prepend[popCitiesTable
  , {"City", "Country", "CountryFlag", "Population"}]
 ]
```

[image]

where only the top 15 cities are displayed.

---

**EDIT**

Borrowing from the answer by @RunnyKine

```
m1 = Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}]}]; (* a marker *)

GeoGraphics[{{White, EdgeForm[Black], 
   CountryData[#, "FullPolygon"] & /@ CountryData[]}
  , GeoMarker[
   popList, m1
   , "Scale" -> 5
   , "Color" -> Red]
  }
 , GeoBackground -> "StreetMapNoLabels"
 (*,GeoCenter\[Rule]Entity["Country", "Singapore"]*)
 , ImageSize -> Large
 ]
```

[image]