# Can NDSolve or another command be used to solve Laplaces equation in an arbiratry 3D volume?

Tags: differential-equations

I am interested in solving the 3D Laplace equation in an arbitrary volume. In particular, I would like to solve the equation in a torus with a noncircular cross-section whose shape varies the long way around the torus.  Can Mathematica (e.g., NDSolve or NDSolveValue) be used to accomplish this, or are the applications limited to 2D domains or simple 3D domains? I am somewhat new to Mathematica, and before launching into trying this, I thought to find out if it is possible.

Comment: It's possible of course: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77179/1871

Comment: I also agree that MMA can do it. You could be interested in [this](http://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/solving-pde-symbolics-numerics/)