# Solving the 3D Poisson equation on the surface of a cube using a relaxation method

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

The code below is from another question asked by someone else about solving the 3D Laplace equation for truncated octahedron in a cube matrix, [How to solve Laplace equation in 3D?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77179/how-to-solve-laplace-equation-in-3d). I wanna know, how would you solve the 3D Poisson equation (which is basically the Laplace equation with a source function), on the surface of a cube, meaning with no boundary conditions, using a relaxation method such as Successive Over Relaxation or Gauss-Seidel or any other relaxation method?

```
 TruncatedOctahedron = {x + y + z <= 10 && x + y - z <= 10 && 
    x - y + z <= 10 && -x + y + z <= 10 && x + y + z >= -10 && 
    x + y - z >= -10 && x - y + z >= -10 && -x + y + z >= -10 && 
    -6 <= x <= 6 && -6 <= y <= 6 && -6 <= z <= 6}；
    Cube = Cuboid[{-100, -100, -100}, {100, 100, 100}];
    Subscript[Γ, D] = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 200., 
    {x, y, z} ∈ TruncatedOctahedron], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 15., {x, y, z} ∈ Cube]};
    Ω = RegionDifference[Cube, TruncatedOctahedron]
    sol = NDSolveValue[{Inactive[Laplacian][u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, 
    Subscript[Γ, D]}, u, {x, y, z} ∈ Ω];
```

Comment: Please add link to previous question, mentioned in the question.

Comment: I don't get what your major concern is. Is it really important to you to obtain the solution by a relaxation method? For this simple PDE on a surface, direct factorizations are usually faster and more robust.

Comment: Moreover, without boundary conditions, the Laplacian as a one-dimensional null space (the constant functions) and since it is selfadjoint, the Laplacian is not surjective (the image is the $L^2$-orthogonal complement of the constant functions). So in general, you can only expect least-squares solutions.

Comment: The equation I really wanna solve is: Laplacian[ u[x,y,z], {x,y,z} ] = Exp[u[x,y,z]]. This  is more complicated and requires a a relaxation method.

Comment: The exponential on the right-hand side makes it more complicated. Do you have any ideas about how I can solve it on the surface of a cube or a sphere without boundary conditions? Thanks Henrik.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an approach that uses the direct solver *Pardiso* along with a vanishing-average constraint in order to obtain the least-squares solution.

Since surface finite elements are not built into *Mathematica* (yet), I use the functions `getSurfaceLaplaceBeltrami`, `getSurfaceMass`, `getSurfaceLaplacianCombinatorics`, `SurfaceLaplaceBeltrami`, and `SurfaceMassMatrix` from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172603). In order to be self-contained, here is their code:

```
Quiet[Block[{xx, x, PP, P, UU, U, VV, V, f, Df, u, Du, v, Dv, g, 
    integrant, quadraturepoints, quadratureweights}, 
   xx = Table[x[[i]], {i, 1, 2}];
   PP = Table[P[[i, j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
   UU = Table[U[[i]], {i, 1, 3}];
   VV = Table[V[[i]], {i, 1, 3}];
   (*local affine parameterization of the surface with respect to the \
"standard triangle"*)
   f = x \[Function] 
     PP[[1]] + x[[1]] (PP[[2]] - PP[[1]]) + x[[2]] (PP[[3]] - PP[[1]]);
   Df = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[f[xx], {xx}]];
   (*the Riemannian pullback metric with respect to f*)
   g = x \[Function] Evaluate[Df[xx]\[Transpose].Df[xx]];
   (*two affine functions u and v and their derivatives*)
   u = x \[Function] 
     UU[[1]] + x[[1]] (UU[[2]] - UU[[1]]) + x[[2]] (UU[[3]] - UU[[1]]);
   Du = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[u[xx], {xx}]];
   v = x \[Function] 
     VV[[1]] + x[[1]] (VV[[2]] - VV[[1]]) + x[[2]] (VV[[3]] - VV[[1]]);
   Dv = x \[Function] Evaluate[D[v[xx], {xx}]];
   integrant = 
    x \[Function] 
     Evaluate[D[D[v[xx] u[xx] Sqrt[Abs[Det[g[xx]]]], {UU}, {VV}]]];
   (*since the integrant is quadratic over each triangle,
   we use a three-
   point Gauss quadrature rule (for the standard triangle)*)
   quadraturepoints = {{0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}};
   quadratureweights = {1/6, 1/6, 1/6};
   getSurfaceMass = 
    With[{code = 
       N[quadratureweights.Map[integrant, quadraturepoints]] /. 
        Part -> Compile`GetElement}, 
     Compile[{{P, _Real, 2}}, code, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]];
   integrant = 
    x \[Function] 
     Evaluate[
      D[D[Dv[xx].Inverse[g[xx]].Du[xx] Sqrt[
          Abs[Det[g[xx]]]], {UU}, {VV}]]];
   (*since the integrant is constant over each trianle,we use a one-
   point Gauss quadrature rule (for the standard triangle)*)
   quadraturepoints = {{1/3, 1/3}};
   quadratureweights = {1/2};
   getSurfaceLaplaceBeltrami = 
    With[{code = 
       N[quadratureweights.Map[integrant, quadraturepoints]] /. 
        Part -> Compile`GetElement}, 
     Compile[{{P, _Real, 2}}, code, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]]]];

getSurfaceLaplacianCombinatorics = 
  Quiet[Module[{ff}, 
    With[{code = 
       Flatten[Table[Table[{ff[[i]], ff[[j]]}, {i, 1, 3}], {j, 1, 3}],
          1] /. Part -> Compile`GetElement}, 
     Compile[{{ff, _Integer, 1}}, code, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]]]];

SurfaceLaplaceBeltrami[pts_, flist_, pat_] := 
  With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"], 
    vals = Flatten[
      getSurfaceLaplaceBeltrami[Partition[pts[[flist]], 3]]]}, 
   Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    SetSystemOptions[
     "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}], 
    SparseArray[Rule[pat, vals], {Length[pts], Length[pts]}, 0.], 
    SetSystemOptions[spopt]]];

SurfaceMassMatrix[pts_, flist_, pat_] := 
  With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"], 
    vals = Flatten[getSurfaceMass[Partition[pts[[flist]], 3]]]}, 
   Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    SetSystemOptions[
     "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}], 
    SparseArray[Rule[pat, vals], {Length[pts], Length[pts]}, 0.], 
    SetSystemOptions[spopt]]];
```

Creating a triangle mesh on the cube:

```
R = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
   Scale[PolyhedronData["Cube", "MeshRegion"], 2], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 0.05}];
```

Assembling mass matrix `M` and stiffness matrix `A`:

```
pts = MeshCoordinates[R];
triangles = MeshCells[R, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]];
pat = Flatten[getSurfaceLaplacianCombinatorics[triangles], 1];
A = SurfaceLaplaceBeltrami[pts, Flatten@triangles, pat]
M = SurfaceMassMatrix[pts, Flatten@triangles, pat]
```

Assembling the saddle point matrix `L` and computing its factorization `S` (the factorization takes a few seconds):

```
a = SparseArray[{Total[M]}];
L = ArrayFlatten[{{A, a\[Transpose]}, {a, 0.}}];
S = LinearSolve[L, Method -> "Pardiso"];
```

Choosing a source function `f` and sampling it in order to obtain a right-hand side `b` for the equation `L.u == b`.

```
f = X \[Function] Cos[15/3 Indexed[X, 1]] + 1/2 Cos[7/3 Indexed[X, 2]] Cos[13/3 Indexed[X, 3]];
b = Join[M.(f /@ pts), {0.}];
```

Solving the linear equation:

```
u = Most@S[b];
```

Plotting the result:

```
Graphics3D[{
  EdgeForm[],
  GraphicsComplex[
   pts,
   Polygon[triangles],
   VertexColors -> ColorData["SunsetColors"] /@ Rescale[u]
   ]
  },
 Lighting -> "Neutral"
 ]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you may use an iterative solver such as `"ConjugateGradient"`:

```
vals = (# - a[[1]].#/Total[a[[1]]]) &[(f /@ pts)];
c = M.vals;
v = LinearSolve[A, c,
   Method -> {"Krylov",
     Method -> "ConjugateGradient",
     "Preconditioner" -> "ILU0", "Tolerance" -> .0001, 
     "MaxIterations" -> 300}
   ];

Max[Abs[A.v - c]]/Max[Abs[c]]
Sqrt[Dot[u - v, M, u - v]]

Max[Abs[A.v - c]]/Max[Abs[c]] (* relative residual *)
Sqrt[Dot[u - v, M, u - v]] (* L^2-distance between the solutions *)
```

> 0.000294991
>
> 0.000087751

## Liouville–Bratu–Gelfand equation

As mentioned in this post, OP wants to solve the following Liouville–Bratu–Gelfand-type equation

$$\Delta u = \exp(u  + h ) -1 = \exp(u) \, \exp(h ) -1,$$

with a prescribed function $h$. We may write down the system as a function `F` for which we search a root. Then we employ `FindRoot` and supply it with the precomputed `Jacobian` of the systen (implemented as `DF`) and a not-to-bad initial guess. `FindRoot` applies Newton's method with line search (the line search seems to be essential here; Newton's method with step size `1` tends to diverge).
One can use an arbitrary function `h`, but OP wants

$$h(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log \| x - p_i\|^2$$

with few source points $p_1,\dotsc,p_n$ on the surface of the cube. So, let's set it up:

```
n = 20;
sources = RandomSample[MeshCoordinates[R], n];
Exphvals = Times @@ DistanceMatrix[sources, MeshCoordinates[R]]^2;

ClearAll[F, DF];
F[u_?VectorQ] := A.u + M.(Exp[u] Exphvals - 1.);
DF[u_?VectorQ] := A + M.DiagonalMatrix[SparseArray[Exp[u] Exphvals]];
u0 = ConstantArray[1., Length[Exphvals]];

u = u /. FindRoot[F[u], {u, u0}, Jacobian :> DF[u]];
Max[Abs[F[u]]]
```

> 4.58583*10^-14

```
Graphics3D[{
  Sphere[sources, 0.05],
  EdgeForm[], 
  GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon[triangles], 
   VertexColors -> ColorData["SunsetColors"] /@ Rescale[u]]
  },
 Lighting -> "Neutral"
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Henrik, this looks great! However I don't understand the various parts of the code. Would you please explain some parts of the code to me. Is the code solving the equation: Laplacian[ u[x,y,z], {x,y,z} ] = Exp[u[x,y,z]]? Is the size of the cube 3x3x3? Thanks for this code, it's very helpful. I would like to make some changes to it to suit the specific problem I'm working on, which is: Laplacian[ u[x,y,z], {x,y,z} ] = (Exp[ u[x,y,z] + h[x,y,z] ]) -1, where h[x,y,z]= Sum [ { Log |{x,y,z} - {x_i, y_i, z_i}|^2 }, { i, 1, N}].

Comment: The point {x_i, y_i, z_i} represents the position of the i-th vortex on the surface of the cube , and {i, 1, N} means that the number of vortices on the surface of the cube range from 1 to N. I have to adjust the code to include all of these things, so that I can vary N and see what happens when I do. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the first code block is about assembling the mass and stiffness matrix; I don't like to go too much into detail, but I can say that a standard Ritz-Galerkin scheme with piecewise-linear testfunctions is employed. I used the standard cube as surface `R`, but you can use any `MeshRegion` or `BoundaryMeshRegion` of dimension 2, immersed into $\mathbb{R}^3$ with triangular faces as `R`. You may replace `f` also by any other source function. With the nonlinear lower-order term, I would use Newton's method. Give me a few minutes I'll see what I can do about it.

Comment: Just to be sure: You want to solve a PDE _on_ the surface of the cube, right? In that case, the code example in your question is very misleading.

Comment: Sure I want to solve the PDE on the surface of the cube. Sorry about the code example I gave. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Please see the edit I made above. Thanks.

Comment: @Thando Okay, I've seen the changes. They are only in the function (as expected), so I made a roll-back. Please specify exactly what the function `h` is supposed to look like. What are the `{x_i, y_i, z_i}`? Note that in _Mathematica_ syntax, underscores (`_`) are _not_  used for indexing and that `N` is a built-in symbol.

Comment: Oh sorry about the syntax. The h[x,y,z]= Sum [ { Log[ (Norm[{x,y,z} - { x[[ i ]], y[[ i ]], z[[ i ]] }])^2 ] }, { i, 1, N}].

Comment: Henrik, what do you mean that you made a roll-back?

Comment: I restored the former version of the post. That is a roll-back.

Comment: @Thando I edited my post a last time. This should give you an idea how to modify the code for future investigations. Please, with sugar on top: Next time, express all detail necessary for understanding your question immediately and directly in your question post. And give a _meaningful_ code example, not a distracting one.  For example, you asked in a comment on my first answering attempt "Is the code solving the equation: Laplacian[ u[x,y,z], {x,y,z} ] = Exp[u[x,y,z]]?" and "Is the size of the cube 3x3x3?" Why _should_ it? This was mentioned _at no point_ in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I put together all the code you provided above and run it. Please see my edit above. I've made a mistake somewhere because when I run it I don't get the nice graphic result that you got. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. How must I run the code as a whole in order to get the result you got? I'm sorry for my inaccurate question post, next time I'll be as clear as possible in my question posts. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I got it. I ran the code and it worked. Thank you so much Henrik. I appreciate it. All the best!

Comment: You're welcome. (You may accept this answer by clicking the checkmark below the up/down vote buttons to the left of this post.)

Answer (score 2):

In version 11.3, no tricks are needed. All scales and amplitudes can be reduced to 1. Code for the Laplace equation with data on a cube and truncated octahedron

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
L = 3/2; L1 = 1; L2 = 3/5; truncatedOctahedron = 
 ImplicitRegion[
  x + y + z <= L1 && x + y - z <= L1 && 
   x - y + z <= L1 && -x + y + z <= L1 && x + y + z >= -L1 && 
   x + y - z >= -L1 && 
   x - y + z >= -L1 && -x + y + z >= -L1 && -L2 <= x <= L2 && -L2 <= 
    y <= L2 && -L2 <= z <= L2, {x, y, z}];
cube = ImplicitRegion[-L <= x <= L && -L <= y <= L && -L <= z <= 
     L, {x, y, z}];

\[CapitalOmega] = RegionDifference[cube, truncatedOctahedron];

sol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[
     u[x, y, z] == 
      0, -L2 <= x <= L2 && -L2 <= y <= L2 && -L2 <= z <= L2], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 1, True]}, 
   u, {x, y, z} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];
{ContourPlot[sol[x, y, 0], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 ContourPlot[sol[0, y, z], {y, -L, L}, {z, -L, L}, Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 ContourPlot[sol[x, 0, z], {x, -L, L}, {z, -L, L}, Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: fig1]
Code for the Poisson equation with data on a cube  and truncated octahedron

```
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 
     Sin[2*x]*Sin[2*y] + Cos[3*z], 
    DirichletCondition[
     u[x, y, z] == 
      0, -L2 <= x <= L2 && -L2 <= y <= L2 && -L2 <= z <= L2], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 1, True]}, 
   u, {x, y, z} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]];


{ContourPlot[sol1[x, y, 0], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 ContourPlot[sol1[0, y, z], {y, -L, L}, {z, -L, L}, Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 ContourPlot[sol1[x, 0, z], {x, -L, L}, {z, -L, L}, Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: Thanks Alex. Would the code work for the problem:  Laplacian[ u[x,y,z], {x,y,z} ] = (Exp[ u[x,y,z] + h[x,y,z] ]) -1, where h[x,y,z]= Sum [ { Log |{x,y,z} - {x_i, y_i, z_i}|^2 }, { i, 1, N}] ?

Comment: You can solve the problem, but you need to formulate the problem first and not at the end. So far everything is very abstract. Do you want to solve a problem in a cuboid, in a sphere or in $\Omega $?

Comment: @Thando Equation `Laplacian[ u[x,y,z], {x,y,z} ] = (Exp[ u[x,y,z] + h[x,y,z] ]) -1` is called Liouville–Bratu–Gelfand equation.

Comment: Cool, I thought it was a Poisson equation. Yes sure I want to solve it on the surface of a cube or the surface of a sphere, which ever is simpler to code.

Comment: @Thando Then what is truncated octahedron and 3D for?

Comment: Sorry about the code example I posted, it is indeed misleading. I just wanna solve the equation: Laplacian[ u[x,y,z], {x,y,z} ] = (Exp[ u[x,y,z] + h[x,y,z] ]) -1, where  h[x,y,z]= Sum [ { Log |{x,y,z} - {x_i, y_i, z_i}|^2 }, { i, 1, N}], on the surface of a cube. There is no truncated octahedron, that just comes from a previous post. Sorry again about that Alex.

Comment: @Thando If you want to get a solution on the surface, then why 3D? There is a big difference between a 3D solution `u[x,y,z]` with data or sources on a cube surface and a 2D solution u[x1,y1] with coordinates `x1,y1` on a cube surface.

Comment: It has to do with the nature of the problem. The problem is about the behavior of topological vortices on the surface of a compact surface without a boundary, which is a sphere or a cube, so it has to be 3D because of that.

Comment: Now it is clear that this is the Liouville field theory on a sphere or cube. There are many articles on this topic. You should start a new topic using the correct name of the equation - Liouville–Bratu–Gelfand equation, and I will prepare a solution on a cube.

Comment: Sure Alex. Thanks.

Comment: I did as you said, here's the link to the new topic: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188474/solving-the-liouville-bratu-gelfand-equation-on-the-surface-of-a-cube

Comment: the code Henrik wrote works great, so I just wanna say thank you for your help Alex, I appreciate it bro. All the best.

Comment: @Thando The code works great, but what does it do?