# Solving 2D Laplace equation for irregular boundaries

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I want to solve Laplace equation in 2D with $x$ and $y$ coordinates with the boundary conditions
 $V(0,y)=-180$;
 $V(x,0)=50x-180$;
 $V(x,6)=50x-180$;
 $V(453.595-\sqrt{450.05^2 - (y - 3)^2},y)=0$
The problem is the fourth boundary is the segment of a circle. I want to find $V(x,y)$ within the boundary.

Is this problem solvable using *Mathematica*? anyone with any idea? I have been struggling with this problem for my research work could find only approximate analytical solution and want to compare the results if solvable by *Mathematica*.

[image]

Comment: Have a look in the documentation: `NDSolve` is what you are looking for. If you need help with something concret why don't you post the code you have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setup The region to solve the PDEs

```
Clear["Global`*"]

xMax = 453.595 - Sqrt[450.05^2 - 3^2];
regA = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {xMax, 6}];
regB = ImplicitRegion[{453.595 - Sqrt[450.05^2 - (y - 3)^2] - x < 0}, 
       {{x, 0, xMax}, {y, 0, 6}}];
reg = RegionDifference[regA, regB];

RegionPlot[reg, AspectRatio -> 1/10]
```

[image]

Solve the PDEs using NDSolve

```
solV = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0,
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, 453.595 - Sqrt[450.05^2 - (y - 3)^2] == x],
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == -180, x == 0],
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 50 x - 180, y == 0],
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 50 x - 180, y == 6]}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] reg]

DensityPlot[solV[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1/10]
```

Potential Map:

[image]

Check out other examples on *Mathematica* [SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59441/solve-laplace-equation-using-ndsolve)

Electric Field Vectors:

```
eleField[x_, y_] = -Grad[solV[x, y], {x, y}];

Show[
 DensityPlot[solV[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1/10, ImageSize -> Full],
 VectorPlot[eleField[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, VectorPoints -> 5, 
  VectorStyle -> Gray, VectorScale -> Small, AspectRatio -> 1/10]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this code solves the Laplace equation for any geometry. Also, the example for finding Electric field is helpful. I appreciate this. Thanks.