# Finding Maximum Value of ElectricField in a bounded region

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, physics

I have been trying to find the maximum value of the magnitude of an electric field in a bounded region. `NDSolve` gives the value of the potential inside the region once we supply the boundary conditions; the negative gradient of the potential gives the the electric field. I have this code which works well, except that it is not giving the maximum value of the electric field. Can anyone suggest the correct way of using `NMaximize` for this case?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = 3.6;
b = 6;
θ = 5*π/180;

Region1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, 6}];
Region2 = Triangle[{{a - b*Tan[θ], 0}, {a, 0}, {a, b}}]
reg = RegionDifference[Region1, Region2];
RegionPlot[reg]
solution = 
 NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, 
    x/Tan[θ] + b - a/Tan[θ] == y], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == -180, x == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 180*x/(a - b*Tan[θ]) - 180, 
    y == 0], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 50 x - 180, y == 6]}, 
  u, {x, y} ∈ reg]
EField[x_, y_] = -Grad[solution[x, y], {x, y}];
ContourPlot[solution[x, y], {x, y} ∈ reg]
VectorPlot[EField[x, y], {x, y} ∈ reg]
NMaximize[{Norm[EField[x, y]], {x, y} ∈ reg}, {x, y}]
```

Comment: Something like this: `EField2[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
  Evaluate[-Grad[solution[x, y], {x, y}]];
NMaximize[{Norm[EField2[x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] 
   solution["ElementMesh"]}, {x, y}]` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

```
NMaximize[{Norm[EField[x, y]], {x, y} ∈ solution["ElementMesh"]}, {x, y}]
```

Which gives:

> {58.362, {x -> 2.95481, y -> 0.186586}}

Showing everything together:

```
{eMax, {xMax, yMax}} = 
 NMaximize[{Norm[EField[x, y]], {x, y} ∈ solution["ElementMesh"]}, {x, y}] /.
  sol : {__Rule} :> Values[sol]

Show[
 DensityPlot[solution[x, y], {x, y} ∈ reg, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> b/a],
 VectorPlot[EField[x, y], {x, y} ∈ reg, VectorPoints -> 7, 
  VectorScale -> Small, VectorColorFunction -> GrayLevel],
 Graphics[{Circle[{xMax, yMax}, 0.05], Text[eMax, {xMax, yMax + 0.15}]}]
 ]
```

[image]

This answer builds on a previous answer given on calculating electric potential for a bounded 2D region: [Solving 2D Laplace equation for irregular boundaries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119325/solving-2d-laplace-equation-for-irregular-boundaries)