# NDSolveValue Quality Issue

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm having trouble with the resolution of the NDSolveValue solution.

For example this code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59441/solve-laplace-equation-using-ndsolve) gives the following on my machine (Windows, Version 10.4.1):

[image]
(Zoomed in to show detail)

```
Ω = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 100}], Rectangle[{40, 40}, {60, 60}]];
sol = NDSolveValue[{
   D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0,
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 100., 
     x == 40 && 40 <= y <= 60 || 
     x == 60 && 40 <= y <= 60 || 
     40 <= x <= 60 && y == 40 || 
     40 <= x <= 60 && y == 60],
   u[x, 0] == u[x, 100] == u[0, y] == u[100, y] == 0
   }, u, {x, y} ∈ Ω]

DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω,  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
            PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends->Automatic]
```

This issue persists even when I use:

```
Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation"}}
```

I've tried reducing the `MaxCellMeasure` to 0.01, increasing `AccuracyGoal`, `PrecisionGoal`, and `WorkingPrecision`, set `InterpolationOrder` to All. None of these changes seem to produce better results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
\[CapitalOmega] = 
 ToElementMesh[
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 100}], 
   Rectangle[{40, 40}, {60, 60}]], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 1}]
```

This will generate a second order mesh and you'll need far fewer elements to get an accurate solution then with a first order mesh (as `DiscretizeRegion` generates)

Ideally you would be able to give the `MaxCellMeasure` to `NDSolve` as a FEM option directly, but that does not seem to work. I'll need to investigate that a bit.

**Update**

This is actually not a problem of `NDSolve` but of the plotting function. If you discretize the region omega then the plotting function (`DensityPlot`) will also see the refined mesh. If the you refine the mesh in `NDSolve` and then extract that mesh and pass it to `DensityPlot` in place of the undiscretized region omega you'll get the result you expect.

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 100., 
    x == 40 && 40 <= y <= 60 || x == 60 && 40 <= y <= 60 || 
     40 <= x <= 60 && y == 40 || 40 <= x <= 60 && y == 60], 
   u[x, 0] == u[x, 100] == u[0, y] == u[100, y] == 0}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 1}}]

DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] sol["ElementMesh"], 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Note that here I used `\[Element] sol["ElementMesh"]`

Comment: When I was struggling with the FEA options in NDSolve, it didn't seem like they were effective. I even tried the 2nd Order mesh inside NDSolve and it had some minor effect but without the ability to change MaxCellMeasure it was almost useless. It also seems like the mesh generation is significantly faster outside of NDSolve.

Comment: @Young, I'll investigate that.

Comment: @Young, thank you for taking the time to reformulate the comment question and put that into a full question.

Answer (score 4):

Using `DiscretizeRegion[]` with `RegionDifference[]` prior to `NDSolveValue` was the key.

```
Ω = 
  DiscretizeRegion[
   RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 100}], 
    Rectangle[{40, 40}, {60, 60}]],
   Method -> "Continuation", AccuracyGoal -> 7, PrecisionGoal -> 7, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.1}];

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 100., 
    x == 40 && 40 <= y <= 60 || x == 60 && 40 <= y <= 60 || 
     40 <= x <= 60 && y == 40 || 40 <= x <= 60 && y == 60], 
   u[x, 0] == u[x, 100] == u[0, y] == u[100, y] == 0},
  u, {x, y} ∈ Ω, InterpolationOrder -> All]

DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]