# Changing the `ExtrapolationHandler` Function in Any Interpolation

Tags: interpolation, undocumented

This is a related question to [What's inside InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 4.}}, <>]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337) and [Suppress extrapolation of interpolating function in a ContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63083).

When interpolating a set of points, one might need to change the extrapolation behaviour, especially setting the function value to zero outside the original bounds of the data *without reducing the performance time considerably*.

It is possible to change the `ExtrapolationHandler` when a **polynomial** interpolation is performed as described in the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63153/27336) by @Michael E2.

However, the same procedure does *not* work with **spline** interpolation (see the minimal code below).

Is there a way to change the default `ExtrapolationHandler` in spline interpolation?

Is it possible to change the default `ExtrapolationHandler` for *all* interpolating commands, like `FunctionInterpolation`, `ListInterpolation`, and `BSplineFunction`?

```
points = Transpose[{Range[0, 10*1.0]/10,RandomReal[{0, 10}, 10+1]}];
(* 10 points on x-axis from 0 to 1 with random numbers between 0 and     
  10 for the y-axis values *)

polyintpF = Interpolation[points, InterpolationOrder -> 2,
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {(0.0 &), "WarningMessage" -> False}];
(* polynomial interpolation of order 2 *)

splineintpF = Interpolation[points, Method -> "Spline",
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {(0.0 &), "WarningMessage" -> False}];
(* spline interpolation *)

polyintpF[2.0] (* gives zero as expected *)

(* extrapolates the function by the 'Automatic ExtrapolationHandler' ! *)
splineintpF[2.0]
```

Answer (score 8):

A walk-around defining an intermediary function (you may want a macro instead):

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
makeNoExtrapFun[fun_, var_, def_] :=
 If[IntervalMemberQ[Interval@@InterpolatingFunctionDomain@fun, var],fun[var],def,def]

f = Interpolation[{1, 2, 1, 2, 1}, Method -> "Spline"];
k[x_] := makeNoExtrapFun[f, x, 0]
Plot[k@x, {x, 0, 8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `k[x]` evaluates to `0`.  Perhaps `IntervalMemberQ` is not the best choice.  I would do something like `Piecewise[{{fun[var],  LessEqual @@ Riffle[First[fun["Domain"]], var]}}, def]` for the body of `makeNoExtrapFun`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I used `If[ ]` just because of its fourth argument

Comment: `If` vs. `Piecewise` is debatable.  The main point is that `IntervalMemberQ` makes the function evaluate to `def` on non-numeric input.  For instance, I'm not sure how to get the derivative of the function `k[x]` with `D`; I believe with my definition, both `D[k[x], x]` and `k'[x]` work.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Recently, after trying several methods, I found that the following easy trick works the best and the fastest (in case of large number of function calls):
Suppose that `f` is a deliberate interpolated function or spline (or B-spline),

```
(* note that 'points' cover the range [xmin, xmax]; see the original question above *)

splineintpF = Interpolation[points, Method -> "Spline"]; (* e.g., spline interpolation *)

f[x_] := 0.; (* first, define f for all x; this will be the 'extrapolation method' *) 
f[x_?(xmin <= # <= xmax &)] := splineintpF[x]; (* then, define f for x
     in the interpolated range [xmin, xmax] *)
```

Now, interpolation/extrapolation yields the expected result in the whole range of the variable, $(-\infty, +\infty)$.
This works particularly faster than defining a `Piecewise` function -- as far as I could measure.