# Overriding default ExtrapolationHandler

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

When modeling systems with `WhenEvent` and `NDSolve` I found that the default extrapolation settings used in the returned `InterpolatingFunction` often cause weird artifacts when plotting the solution. As an example take the following image. It shows the solution of a bouncing ball problem where `WhenEvent` is used both to let the ball rebound and to stop integration after five bounces.

[image]

The code that generated the image is:

```
bouncingBall[e_] := Module[{i = 0}, 
NDSolve[{y''[t] == -9.81, x''[t] == 0, x'[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1,
WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, {y'[t] -> - e y'[t], i++ , If[i == 5, "StopIntegration"]}]}, 
{x, y}, {t, 0, 5}]]

ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. bouncingBall[0.79] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 5},
PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-1, 1.5}}]
```

From [Michael E2' answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63153/4597) I know that the undocumented but well known option `"ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, "WarningMessage" -> False}` solves the issue.

For the sake of demoing code to people not familiar with Mathematica I would like to temporarily override the standard extrapolation settings so that I don't have to explain to the audience what this arcane code snipped does.

I tried using `SetOptions` on both `NDSolve` and `InterpolatingFunction` but in both cases one gets an error message that this is not a known option.

```
SetOptions[#,"ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &,
"WarningMessage" -> False}] & /@ {NDSolve, InterpolatingFunction}
```

> SetOptions::optnf: "!(\"ExtrapolationHandler\") is not a known option for NDSolve."
>    SetOptions::optnf: "!(\"ExtrapolationHandler\") is not a known option for InterpolatingFunction."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SetOptions` does not work with hidden options, but try the following to obtain the desired result

```
Unprotect[NDSolve]; 
AppendTo[Options[NDSolve], 
  {"ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &,"WarningMessage" -> False}}]; 
Protect[NDSolve];
```

[image]