# Suppress extrapolation in `TimeSeriesResample`

Tags: interpolation, time-series

Although I'm aware of several workarounds available to handle the extrapolation warnings raised by the interpolation that takes place in some built-in functions (e.g., [`ContourPlot`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63153/260)), I find the `"ExtrapolationHandler"` option cannot be used directly inside the `ResamplingMethod` of `TimeSeriesResample`.

For instance,

```
TimeSeriesResample[TimeSeries[Table[{i, RandomReal[]}, {i,300}]], {Range[301]}]
```

will raise the following warning:

> InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {301} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

As such, my question is: 
what is an elegant way of handling extrapolation raised by `TimeSeriesResample`? i.e., detect the range outliers and take action on them.
I want something like `"ExtrapolationHandler"` in `Interpolation`.

Comment: It is not clear whether you want to suppress the warning message or detect it in your code and take action.

Comment: @m_goldberg, I meant the latter: how to detect the outliers and take action on them.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = Table[{i, 100 + i}, {i, 3}];
```

You avoid the warning by specifying a resampling method

```
ts = TimeSeriesResample[TimeSeries@data, {Range@4}, ResamplingMethod -> None]["Path"]
```

> {{1, 101}, {2, 102}, {3, 103}, {4, Missing[]}}

Now you can delete or replace the missing value, f.e.

```
ts /. {_, Missing[]} :> Sequence[]
```

> {{1, 0.243066}, {2, 0.455276}, {3, 0.0923567}}

You can also use

```
TimeSeriesResample[TimeSeries@data, {Range@4},
  ResamplingMethod -> {"Constant", c}] // Normal
```

> {{1, 101}, {2, 102}, {3, 103}, {4, c}}

Comment: thanks for the answer! But I was thinking if Interpolation could be used while the outliers could be removed or replaced as `Missing[]`.