# How to deal with slow convergence of FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving

As a simple example let's consider the function $f(x) = x \left(1-\frac{x}{3}\right) \left(\frac{x}{10}-1\right)$:

```
f[x_] := x (1-x/3) (x/10-1)
```

I want to find, $r(c)$, the root of the function $f(x)+c$ that is closer to $0$ for $c\in[0,1]$.

The value of the local minimum of $f$ is $c_{\text{min}}=-0.642389\dots$, this implies that for $c\le -c_{\text{min}}$, $r(c) < 1.38$ and for $c > -c_{\text{min}}$, $r(c) > 10.25$.

The problem of course is that if I call `FindRoot` with $0$ as the initial point,for $c=-c_{\text{min}}+\varepsilon$ the function $f(x)+c$ come close to the $x$ axis and the algorithm takes too long to converge.

Is there any way to tell mathematica that if it takes too long to find a root starting at 0, it should instead start at 10?

I would like to be able to plot the discontinuous function $r(c)$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I forgot some minus signs. Sorry about that. I fixed it now.

Comment: Perhaps try `NSolve[eq, x, Reals]` and analyze the root closest to zero.  Might depend on how complicated your actual $f(x)$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) for a function that can't be handled with [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve). Your function:

```
f[x_] := x (1-x/3) (x/10-1)

eqn = f[x[t]] + t == 0;
```

The corresponding ODE:

```
ode = D[eqn, t];
ode //TeXForm
```

> $\left(1-\frac{x(t)}{3}\right) \left(\frac{x(t)}{10}-1\right) x'(t)+\frac{1}{10}
>    \left(1-\frac{x(t)}{3}\right) x(t) x'(t)-\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{x(t)}{10}-1\right) x(t) x'(t)+1=0$

To use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) we will need initial conditions. Clearly:

```
t == -f[x[t]]
```

so we can use the initial conditions:

```
x[-f[0]] == 0
```

> x[0] == 0

or

```
x[-f[11]] == 11
```

> x[44/15] == 11

Now we are ready to use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue):

```
left = NDSolveValue[
    {ode, x[-f[0]] == 0},
    x,
    {t, 0, 1},
    "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Infinity&, "WarningMessage"->False}
];

right = NDSolveValue[
    {ode, x[-f[11]] == 11},
    x,
    {t, 0, 1}
];

min[t_] := Min[left[t], right[t]]
```

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At t == 0.6423882561207013`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

*(See @MichaelE2's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63153/45431) to the question [Suppress extrapolation of interpolating function in a ContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63083/45431) for an explanation of the "ExtrapolationHandler" option)*

Visualization:

```
Plot[min[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is genius!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

Using

```
r[c_] := x /. NSolve[f[x] + c, x, Reals]
Show[
 Plot[r[c], {c, 0, 1/405 (-442 + 79 Sqrt[79])}], 
 Plot[r[c], {c, 1/405 (-442 + 79 Sqrt[79]), 1}]
, PlotRange -> All]
```

I get the plot

[image]

in under 0.3 seconds on my laptop.

To plot $r(c)$, just use

```
Plot[Min[r[c]], {c, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> {1/405 (-442 + 79 Sqrt[79])}]
```

which yields

[image]

as one would expect.

Comment: Well, yes, but I would like it to be possible without having explicit information about $f$. I know that my $f$ behaves like that locally, and I want the smallest positive root.

Comment: Also `NSolve` cannot deal with any function and sometimes does not work.