# How do you interpolate outside the range of data?

Tags: interpolation

I've got a simple interpolation function using data from an external program.  For values above 3,000, the function reaches a limit.

```
FreeElectronFractionData = {{3000.000, 1.0829044}, {2999.700, 1.0828636}, {2999.400, 1.0828634}, {2999.100, 1.0828633}, ... {2.701, 0.0000003}, {2.401, 0.0000003}, {2.101, 0.0000003}, {1.801, 0.0000003}, {1.501, 0.0000003}, {1.201, 0.0000003}, {0.901, 0.0000003}, {0.601, 0.0000003}, {0.301, 0.0000003}, {0.000, 0.0000003}};

FreeElectronFraction := Interpolation[FreeElectronFractionData];
```

When I give the FreeElectronFraction function a value greater than 3,000, I get the message:

```
FreeElectronFraction[4000]
Input value {4000} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
```

I don't want this.  I know that anything over 3,000 has a value of 1.0829.  What I want is something like:

```
FreeElectronFractionData = {{∞, 1.0829044}, {3000.000, 1.0829044}, {2999.700, 1.0828636}, ...
```

But $\infty$ doesn't appear to be a real number, so Mathematica rejects it.  How do you handle the case of a simple interpolation of a data set with a limit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the undocumented argument `"ExtrapolationHandler"`, which I learned about [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63153/731), together with `ConditionalExpression` as recommended by @CarlWoll in the comments:

```
freeElectronFractionData = {{3000.000, 1.0829044}, {2999.700, 
    1.0828636}, {2999.400, 1.0828634}, {2999.100, 1.0828633}, {2.701, 
    0.0000003}, {2.401, 0.0000003}, {2.101, 0.0000003}, {1.801, 
    0.0000003}, {1.501, 0.0000003}, {1.201, 0.0000003}, {0.901, 
    0.0000003}, {0.601, 0.0000003}, {0.301, 0.0000003}, {0.000, 
    0.0000003}};

freeElectronFraction = Interpolation[
   freeElectronFractionData,
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {
     ConditionalExpression[1.0829044, # > 3000] &,
     "WarningMessage" -> False
     }
   ];

Plot[freeElectronFraction[x], {x, 0, 5000}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @DonaldAirey Posted something better now.

Comment: Yeah, that looks more like it.  I saw the "ExtrapolationHandler", but like you said, there wasn't enough documentation behind it that I could use it.  Good work.

Comment: I would use `ConditionalExpression[1.0829044, #>3000]&` instead, so that you don't return 1.0829044 for numbers below 0.

Comment: @CarlWoll Good idea, I updated to add that.

Comment: This solution still returns an error when you give it $\infty$ as an argument.

Comment: @DonaldAirey I cannot reproduce any errors, but it does stay unevaluated because `InterpolatingFunction` only accepts numeric input, it seems.