# How to make a 3D topographic globe?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, geography

I've made some attempt with this [dataset of elevation](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO5/TOPO/ETOPO5/ETOPO5.DAT).

But I have some trouble with `ListSurfacePlot3D`, which can not show the globe correctly:
[image: my attempt]

And I've checked that the data is not the problem, since the same data drawn by `ListPointPlot3D` shows a globe:

[image: another attempt]

By the way, my goal is to make a topographic globe which shows 3D mountains and sea basins like this:

[image: a globe]

Here is my code:

```
(*elev data input*)
elev1d = BinaryReadList["D:\\topo\\ETOPO5.DAT", {"Integer16"}, ByteOrdering -> +1];
elev2d = ArrayReshape[elev1d, {2160, 4320}];
lati = Flatten @
   Transpose @ Table[Rest @ Table[i, {i, 90, -90, -1/12}], {4320}];
long = Flatten @ Table[Rest @ Table[i, {i, 0, 360, 1/12}], {2160}];
(* make a {lat, lon, altitude} matrix*)
elevlatlon = Transpose @ {lati, long, Flatten @ elev1d};
(*select part of the huge amount of data, add mean earth radius to altitude*)
elevlatlonInUse = (elevlatlon[[;; ;; 12, All]] /.
{m_, n_, o_} -> {m, n, o/200 + 6721}) /. {x_, y /; y > 180, z_} -> {x, y - 360, z};
coordsToXYZ[list_] := Transpose[{Cos[#[[1]]*Pi/180.]*Cos[#[[2]]*Pi/180.]*#[[3]], 
                                 Cos[#[[1]]*Pi/180.]*Sin[#[[2]]*Pi/180.]*#[[3]], 
                                 Sin[#[[1]]*Pi/180.]*#[[3]]} & @ Transpose[list]]
xyz = First[coordsToXYZ /@ {elevlatlonInUse}];
ListPointPlot3D[xyz, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
ListSurfacePlot3D[xyz, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

It's a little different from [How to make a 3D globe?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3646). That's a globe with a 2D texture covering it, but this is a real 3D globe with elevations shown in 3D as well.

P.S. Someone reminded me that, compared with the radius of the Earth (about $6371 \text{ km}$), even Mt. Everest ($8.8\text{ km}$) and the Marianas Trench ($-11\text{ km}$) can be ignored. That's true, I know, but to draw a globe with bumps, we can just scale the elevation. A visualized topographic globe is just for presentation, and not for calculation.

Comment: Mt Everest is 8Km high and the Earth radius is 6371Km. I don't think you'll be able to perceive any bumps.

Comment: The link you give to your topographic data is broken.

Comment: It's the direct URL to ETOPO5.DAT file. Maybe your browser mistake it as a page,just save it. I've tried it still works.Or you can find it here:http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO5/TOPO/ETOPO5

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This answer is intended to demonstrate a neat method I'd recently learned for constructing interpolating functions over the sphere.

A persistent problem dogging a lot of interpolation methods on the sphere has been the subject of what to do at the poles. A recently studied method, dubbed the "double Fourier sphere method" in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/15M1045855) (based on earlier work by [Merilees](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00046973.1973.9648342)) copes remarkably well. This is based on constructing a periodic extension/reflection of the data over at the poles, and then subjecting the resulting matrix to a low-rank approximation. The first reference gives a sophisticated method based on structured Gaussian elimination; in this answer, to keep things simple (at the expense of some slowness), I will use SVD instead.

As I noted in [this Wolfram Community post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/904476), one can conveniently obtain elevation data for the Earth through `GeoElevationData[]`. Here is some elevation data with modest resolution (those with sufficient computing power might consider increasing the `GeoZoomLevel` setting):

```
gdm = Reverse[QuantityMagnitude[GeoElevationData["World", "Geodetic",
              GeoZoomLevel -> 2, UnitSystem -> "Metric"]]];
```

The DFS trick is remarkably simple:

```
gdmdfst = Join[gdm, Reverse[RotateLeft[gdm, {0, Length[gdm]}]]];
```

This yields a $1024\times 1024$ matrix. We now take its SVD:

```
{uv, s, vv} = SingularValueDecomposition[gdmdfst];
```

To construct the required low-rank approximations, we treat the left and right singular vectors (`uv` and `vv`) as interpolation data. Here is a routine for trigonometric fitting (code originally from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87567), but made slightly more convenient):

```
trigFit[data_?VectorQ, n : (_Integer?Positive | Automatic) : Automatic,
        {x_, x0_: 0, x1_}] :=
    Module[{c0, clist, cof, k, l, m, t},
           l = Quotient[Length[data] - 1, 2]; m = If[n === Automatic, l, Min[n, l]];
           cof = If[! VectorQ[data, InexactNumberQ], N[data], data];
           clist = Rest[cof]/2;
           cof = Prepend[{1, I}.{{1, 1}, {1, -1}}.{clist, Reverse[clist]}, First[cof]];
           cof = Fourier[cof, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}];
           c0 = Chop[First[cof]]; clist = Rest[cof];
           cof = Chop[Take[{{1, 1}, {-1, 1}}.{clist, Reverse[clist]}, 2, m]];
           t = Rescale[x, {x0, x1}, {0, 2 π}];
           c0 + Total[MapThread[Dot, {cof, Transpose[Table[{Cos[k t], Sin[k t]},
                                                           {k, m}]]}]]]
```

Now, convert the singular vectors into trigonometric interpolants (and extract the singular values as well):

```
vals = Diagonal[s];
usc = trigFit[#, {φ, 2 π}] & /@ Transpose[uv];
vsc = trigFit[#, {θ, 2 π}] & /@ Transpose[vv];
```

Now, build the spherical interpolant, taking as many singular values and vectors as seen fit (I arbitrarily chose $\ell=768$, corresponding to $3/4$ of the singular values), and construct it as a compiled function for added efficiency:

```
l = 768; (* increase or decrease as needed *)
earthFun = With[{fun = Total[Take[vals, l] Take[usc, l] Take[vsc, l]]}, 
                Compile[{{θ, _Real}, {φ, _Real}}, fun, 
                        Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
                        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]];
```

Now, for the plots. Here is an appropriate color gradient:

```
myGradient1 = Blend[{{-8000, RGBColor["#000000"]}, {-7000, RGBColor["#141E35"]},
                     {-6000, RGBColor["#263C6A"]}, {-5000, RGBColor["#2E5085"]},
                     {-4000, RGBColor["#3563A0"]}, {-3000, RGBColor["#4897D3"]},
                     {-2000, RGBColor["#5AB9E9"]}, {-1000, RGBColor["#8DD2EF"]},
                     {0, RGBColor["#F5FFFF"]}, {0, RGBColor["#699885"]},
                     {50, RGBColor["#76A992"]}, {200, RGBColor["#83B59B"]},
                     {600, RGBColor["#A5C0A7"]}, {1000, RGBColor["#D3C9B3"]},
                     {2000, RGBColor["#D4B8A4"]}, {3000, RGBColor["#DCDCDC"]},
                     {5000, RGBColor["#EEEEEE"]}, {6000, RGBColor["#F6F7F6"]},
                     {7000, RGBColor["#FAFAFA"]}, {8000, RGBColor["#FFFFFF"]}}, #] &;
```

Let's start with a density plot:

```
DensityPlot[earthFun[θ, φ], {θ, 0, 2 π}, {φ, 0, π},
            AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> myGradient1,
            ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Frame -> False, PlotPoints -> 185, 
            PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Earth map constructed from DFS trigonometric interpolant]

Due to the large amount of terms, the plotting is a bit slow, even with the compilation. One might consider using e.g. the [Goertzel-Reinsch algorithm](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=fh3vBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA90) for added efficiency, which I leave to the interested reader to try out.

For comparison, here are plots constructed from approximations of even lower rank ($\ell=128,256,512$), compared with a `ListDensityPlot[]` of the raw data (bottom right):

[image: low rank approximations of Earth]

Finally, we can look at an actual globe:

```
With[{s = 2*^5},
     ParametricPlot3D[(1 + earthFun[θ, φ]/s)
                      {Sin[φ] Cos[θ], Sin[φ] Sin[θ], -Cos[φ]} // Evaluate,
                      {θ, 0, 2 π}, {φ, 0, π}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, 
                      ColorFunction -> (With[{r = Norm[{#1, #2, #3}]}, 
                                              myGradient1[s r - s]] &),
                      ColorFunctionScaling -> False, MaxRecursion -> 1,
                      Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> {500, 250}]] // Quiet
```

[image: DFS globe]

(I had chosen the scaling factor `s` to make the depressions and elevations slightly more prominent, just like in my Community post.)

Of course, using all the singular values and vectors will result in an interpolation of the data (tho it is even more expensive to evaluate). It is remarkable, however, that even the low-rank DFS approximations already do pretty well.

Comment: you've done it so great!thx!

Comment: Well, better late than never, eh? ;)

Answer (score 27):

Too long for a comment, but here's one approach, using information readily available in the docs and on this site:

First, [make a map that wraps a globe](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/geographic-visualization/make-a-map-that-wraps-a-globe.html), changing the `GeoProjection` to something a bit more useful.

```
img = With[{Δ = 30}, 
 Row[Table[
   GeoGraphics[GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["ReliefMap"], 
     GeoRange -> {{-90, 90}, {λ, λ + Δ}},
     GeoProjection -> {"Equirectangular", "Centering" -> {0, λ + Δ/2}}, 
     ImageSize -> Small, 
     GeoGridLines -> Quantity[10, "AngularDegrees"], 
     GeoGridLinesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.4, 0.5]], {λ, -180, 180 - Δ, Δ}]]]
```

[image]

Then use one of the answers to [How to make a 3D globe](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3660/7167) and my lazy animation routine.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, 0, π}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, 
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, 1 - #5} &), 
  Boxed -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> Texture[img], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", 
  Axes -> False, 
  RotationAction -> "Clip", 
  ViewPoint -> {-2.026774, 2.07922, 1.73753418}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Comment: And then they talk about "intelligent design"! +1

Comment: @belisarius It's a New Kind of Geography.

Comment: Although it doesn't show the mountains and the rest in 3D does it?

Comment: @Öskå no, it's just a texture.

Comment: @Öskå No, I was a bit surprised that the topography in the ocean looks reasonable, but not on land.  It does look slightly better in the notebook, so perhaps this is an image compression issue.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to @shrx 's advice to use other coordinates.

After some tuning, it finally works. It's a little ugly, but it's something I really want. The surface near the equator still has some bugs which makes it seem strange.

Here is the code and renderings, which need further optimization.

```
elev1d = BinaryReadList["D:\\topo\\ETOPO5.DAT", {"Integer16"}, ByteOrdering -> +1];
elev2d = ArrayReshape[elev1d, {2160, 4320}]/5 + 6731;
elevplot2d = ListContourPlot[elev2d[[2160 ;; 1 ;; -6, 1 ;; 4320 ;; 6]], ContourStyle -> None,
ColorFunction -> "Topographic", Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> 0.5, ImageSize -> Full,
PlotRangePadding -> None];
ParametricPlot3D[{
elev2d[[Ceiling@(lat/Pi*180*12), Ceiling@(lon/Pi*180*12)]]*Cos[lon]*Sin[lat],
elev2d[[Ceiling@(lat/Pi*180*12), Ceiling@(lon/Pi*180*12)]]*Sin[lon]*Sin[lat],
elev2d[[Ceiling@(lat/Pi*180*12), Ceiling@(lon/Pi*180*12)]]*Cos[lat]},
{lon, 0, 2 Pi}, {lat, -Pi, 0}, TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, 1 - #5} &),
PlotStyle -> Texture[Show[elevplot2d, ImageSize -> 1000]],
Lighting -> "Neutral",RotationAction -> "Clip",Mesh -> None,Axes -> False,PlotPoints -> 25]
```

[image: my globe]

Update: add sea level.

```
elev1d = BinaryReadList["D:\\topo\\ETOPO5.DAT", {"Integer16"}, ByteOrdering -> +1];
elev2d = ArrayReshape[elev1d, {2160, 4320}]/5 + 6731;
elevplot2d = ListContourPlot[elev2d[[2160 ;; 1 ;; -6, 1 ;; 4320 ;; 6]], ContourStyle -> None, ColorFunction -> "Topographic", Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> 0.5, ImageSize -> Full, PlotRangePadding -> None];
sealevel3d = ParametricPlot3D[ {6731*Cos[lon]*Sin[lat], 6731*Sin[lon]*Sin[lat], 6731*Cos[lat]}, {lon, 0, 2 Pi}, {lat, -Pi, 0}, Lighting -> "Neutral", RotationAction -> "Clip", Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Blue] ];
terr3d = ParametricPlot3D[ {elev2d[[Round@(lat/Pi*180*12), Round@(lon/Pi*180*12)]]*Cos[lon]* Sin[lat], elev2d[[Round@(lat/Pi*180*12), Round@(lon/Pi*180*12)]]*Sin[lon]* Sin[lat], elev2d[[Round@(lat/Pi*180*12), Round@(lon/Pi*180*12)]]*Cos[lat]}, {lon, 0, 2 Pi}, {lat, -Pi, 0}, TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({1-#4, 1 - #5} &), PlotStyle -> Texture[Show[elevplot2d, ImageSize -> 1000]], Lighting -> "Neutral", RotationAction -> "Clip", Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> 35, Boxed -> False ];
Show[sealevel3d, terr3d]
```

[image: my globe]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your data is sorted in such a way that `ListSurfacePlot3D` can't draw the surfaces correctly. You can fix it by scrambling the data:

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[RandomSample[xyz, 100000], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, this gets very slow with the increasing number of points and I'm assuming it won't be able to draw the elevation changes to your desired resolution. I'm not sure the `{x,y,z}` structure is the best here, it could be better to use spherical coordinates and remove many of those points that lie on the same spherical surface and are thus redundant.