# How to plot the 3D-boundary of California or other states

Tags: graphics3d, geography

I can get the postion with this code

```
pos = First[
  Flatten[#, 1] & /@ 
   First[Entity[
      "AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}][
     EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Polygon"]]]]
```

You can see the postion in the map

```
GeoListPlot[GeoPosition[pos]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can get their elevation

```
eleData = 
 QuantityMagnitude[
  GeoElevationData[
   Flatten[#, 1] & /@ 
    First[Entity[
       "AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}][
      EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Polygon"]]]]]
```

Then I get the data

```
data = Flatten /@ Transpose[{pos, List /@ eleData}]
```

I can plot its discrete plot

```
ListPointPlot3D[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But how to connected those discrete points to get a **smooth boundary**?

Comment: If the points are returned in order, you could try `ListLinePlot[pos]`.  The islands might cause a few problems.

Comment: @QuantumDot `ListLinePlot` can plot 3D graphics?

Comment: Some answers do essentially the same thing [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/how-to-make-a-3d-globe), but with countries instead of a single state.  Somewhat related: [(60427)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60427/how-to-make-a-3d-topographic-globe)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the links,but in my case,I just want to get the boundary

Comment: Yep, and that's what the answer in the question does.  ("Wireframe": just change to `FaceForm[None]` or change `Polygon` to `Line` and append the first point(s) to the end(s).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach is similar to [Yode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155948/4346)'s answer, but to refine the boundary into smaller segments before calling `GeoElevationData`.

```
poly = EntityValue[
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}], 
  "Polygon"
] /. GeoPosition -> Identity;
```

Refine the boundary by imposing a maximum length:

```
bd = DiscretizeRegion[RegionBoundary[poly], MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> .1}];
```

Now replace each 2D coordinate with it's 3D version. Here we make one bulk call to `GeoElevationData` to avoid the overhead of many server calls:

```
raw = GeoElevationData[GeoPosition[MeshCoordinates[bd]], Automatic, "GeoPosition"];
pts3D = First[raw][[All, {2, 1, 3}]];
```

Now we construct a `MeshRegion` (or equivalently we could use `Graphics3D` + `GraphicsComplex`):

```
ratio = Divide @@ Subtract @@@ RegionBounds[bd];
MeshRegion[pts3D, MeshCells[bd, 1], BoxRatios -> {ratio, 1, .1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's another (slightly hacky) approach. The idea is to take the `BoundaryMeshRegion` from `GeoElevationData`, take only the top, then take the topological boundary.

First the `BoundaryMeshRegion`:

```
cali = Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}];
reg = GeoElevationData[cali, Automatic, "Region"]
```

[image]

To get the top portion of this region, I select the primitives free of a coordinate that's at the bottom of the region:

```
floor = RegionBounds[reg][[3, 1]];
prims = Select[MeshPrimitives[reg, 2], FreeQ[floor]];
```

Visualize this:

```
DiscretizeGraphics[prims]
```

[image]

I then tally the each line segment of each triangle and select the ones with multiplicity one. This will give me the boundary:

```
segs = Catenate[Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ prims[[All, 1]]];
boundary = Cases[Tally[Sort /@ segs], {_, 1}][[All, 1]];
```

To visualize, I exaggerate the z box ratio, assuring the xy ratios are to scale:

```
ratio = Divide @@ Most[Subtract @@@ RegionBounds[reg]];
Graphics3D[Line[segs], BoxRatios -> {1, ratio, .1}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I was trying to separate out the islands with `ConnectedMeshComponents[]`, but my machine hung. :o Nice solution!

Comment: It is a magic....

Answer (score 5):

As you geo-polygon has the 2D coordinates you need.  However, the coordinate system of[`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) and [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics.html) are not the same.  You need to [`Reverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reverse.html) the geo-polygon coordinate pairs to make them compatible in graphics. The [`GeoPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoPosition.html) head must also be removed. Finally a z-axis coordinate should be added (I used [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html)) for the polygon in `Graphics3D`.

With

```
geoPoly = 
 Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}][
  EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "Polygon"]]
```

Then

```
Graphics3D@
 MapAt[Append[0], {All, All, All}]@
  Reverse[geoPoly /. GeoPosition -> Identity, 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed the elevation data information in my original post..That so sorry..But I have updated it.

Comment: `EntityValue[
 Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}], 
 EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", 
  "Polygon", {"ZoomLevel" -> 9}]]` get better result

Answer (score 5):

Here's one possible method:

```
california = Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}];

bounds = GeoBounds[california];
cheights = Reverse[QuantityMagnitude[GeoElevationData[Transpose[bounds],
                                                      GeoZoomLevel -> 4,
                                                      UnitSystem -> "Metric"]]];
crf = RegionMember[MapAt[Map[Reverse[#, 2] &, QuantityMagnitude[LatitudeLongitude[#]]] &, 
                         EntityValue[california, "Polygon"], 1]];

ListPlot3D[cheights, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, DataRange -> Reverse[bounds],
           Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> None, RegionFunction -> (crf[{#1, #2}] &)]
```

[image: 3D boundary of California]

---

Use `Cases[]` as usual if you need the actual `Line[]` objects.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed the elevation data information in my original post..That so sorry..But I have updated it.

Comment: That's OK; I got what you meant, as you can see from the figure in this answer.

Comment: Yes,it is indeed.

Comment: Could we have any fast solution?I like your result but I have to say to get that `cheights` will cost too many time..

Comment: @yode - "fast" in this case also means "low resolution"; that would be the equivalent of just mapping `GeoElevationData[]` on the boundary points of the region, which is similar to what you did in the OP.

Comment: Actually I want to get [all state bounday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Gz8.jpg) in a USA map.But maybe my internet too bad to get those curated data

Comment: @yode, yes, that'd be hard to do, especially under the Great Firewall. (FWIW, my Internet is also slow, and it took me eight tries before `cheights` returned the expected `QuantityArray[]`.)

Comment: `EntityValue[
 Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}], 
 EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", 
  "Polygon", {"ZoomLevel" -> 8}]]` get better result.And more fast.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that can take a `"ZoomLevel"` setting! I'll try that later, as I'm busy with something else at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the [J.M](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) and [Edmund](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19542/edmund)'s answer,I figure out more faster method based on `Entity`

```
poly = EntityValue[
    Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}], 
    EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", 
     "Polygon", {"ZoomLevel" -> 6}]] /. GeoPosition -> Identity;
shape = MapAt[
   Append[Reverse[#], QuantityMagnitude[GeoElevationData[#]]] &, 
   poly, {All, All, All}];
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[], shape}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/3}]
```

[image]

Comment: So you don't want the real spatial configuration, but one where sea-level is assumed to be flat and lines of longitude are assumed to be parallel? (The non-flat coastline in the graphics is, I assume, due to numerical error in the data. That's not what I'm asking about. The coast viewed from the side should show the earth's curvature and not be roughly level.)