# How could I add the WorldMap skin to this parametricPlot3d?

Tags: manipulate, image-processing

How could I stamp the worldmap inthis sphere of variable radius?

I´m interested in the meridian of greenwich (longitude=length=0 Degree) is in the position of the longitude=length=0ºDegree of the parameter v in the parametric plot.

What I´m searching is the relation between the world map and the angles of the parametricplot

```
Manipulate[
 Show[

  ParametricPlot3D[
   r*{ Cos[u]*Sin[v], Cos[u]*Cos[v], Sin[u]}, {u, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, 0,
     2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {-9, 9}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.74]]}, 
   Mesh -> {paralelos, meridianos}]
  ]
 , {{r, 6, "Radio de la esfera"}, 1, rtop, Appearance -> "Open"}

 , {{paralelos, 5, "Numero de Paralelos"}, 1, 25, 2, 
  Appearance -> "Open"}
 , {{meridianos, 16, "Número de Meridianos"}, 0, 40, 4, 
  Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

Comment: refer to [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/how-to-make-a-3d-globe)

Comment: also the example [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/ConstructAGlobeShowingAllWeatherStations.html)