# eigenoscillations of a sphere

Tags: graphics3d, animation

I would like to animate the eigenoscillations of a sphere (Earth?).
It's just simple to draw images one by one:

```
SphericalPlot3D[{1 + 
   0.25*Re[SphericalHarmonicY[6, 3, th, phi]]}, {th, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 
  2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> {16, 32}]
```

[image]

but how to change m and l arbitrary to see, how a sphere vibrate. I've made this years ago, but I forgot..
Regards, Darko

Comment: Do you have an equation for how `m` and `l` change with time, or is it stochastic?  (you say "arbitrary")

Comment: I would guess that (for the right set of equations) the dependence on t would be on the radial component. So simply varying the "amplitude" harmonically would yield a vibrating sphere. But what are the equations? Is it an elastic body? Is it an elastic body oscillating under its own gravity? Is it a bubble? These are different physical problems that would have different solutions.

Answer (score 9):

So I can't seem to find a nice plottable form for the normal modes of an elastic sphere, if you can please let me know.  [This](http://info.computationalscience.nl/papers/archive/Rue96_1.pdf) talks about the vector spherical harmonics, and people often show [sketches](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~nowack/geos557/lecture16-dir/lecture16.htm) of the displacements involved in the fundamental and overtones for the spheroidal and toroidal modes, but I don't find plottable equation forms for them (or I don't understand them enough to plot them).

So let's just take your vibrational mode to be a simple cosine multiplying the spherical harmonic, and since we aren't actually modeling seismic activity we can just [put a map of the Earth on the sphere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3695/9490) to make it seem as though we are.

```
pic = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
   Table[{ColorData["DarkTerrain"][Random[]], 
     CountryData[
      country, {"FullPolygon", "Equirectangular"}]}, {country, 
     Append[CountryData[], "Antarctica"]}]}, 
  Background -> Lighter[ColorData["Aquamarine"][1], 0.5], 
  PlotRangePadding -> None];
ListAnimate[SphericalPlot3D[1 + 0.25*Re[
        Exp[I 2 π #] SphericalHarmonicY[6, 3, u, v]], {u, 0, 
      Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
     PlotPoints -> 50,
     Mesh -> True,
     Axes -> False,
     TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, 1 - #4} &),
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[pic],
       Specularity[White, 50]], Lighting -> "Neutral",
     Boxed -> False] & /@ Range[0, 1, .01]];
```

[image]

Comment: That's cool! +1

Comment: Thanks!  I really wish I could actually plot the "normal modes of the earth", but this will suffice

Comment: Thank you, JasonB, it's just so, like a bubble of water in space. Only without Earth (no memory error).

Comment: @Darko - try removing the `,
     TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, 1 - #4} &),
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[pic],
       Specularity[White, 50]], Lighting -> "Neutral"` commands and add `ColorFunction->(ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#6]&)`

Comment: If that fails, take out the `PlotPoints -> 50,`

Comment: Almost got dizzy by looking at the solution. Imagine what would happen to inhabitants ...