# Pixel perfect world map with no border lines

Tags: graphics, image-processing, geography, projection

I'm trying to build a real world map in Minecraft and want a pixel-perfect raster image I can copy pixel for block.

How can I modify

```
CountryData["World", {"Shape", "Robinson"}]
```

which gives

[image: bad map]

such that:

- Each country is its own separate color (random colors are fine).
- The water color is distinct from the background.
- There are no black border lines (but the borders are still clear from the color difference in countries).
- There is no anti-aliasing or color blending between regions of different colors, be they countries, water, or the background.
- I can scale the map to the exact width (or height) in pixels I want.

Sorry if this is asking a bit much. Mathematica is completely new to me and I wasn't getting anywhere fumbling around with `CountryData` and `GeoGraphics` and `WorldPlot` for an hour.

Comment: What version are you on?

Comment: @J.M. The pilot release for Raspberry Pi (10.0.0.0).

Comment: Would `Graphics[Riffle[CountryData["World", {"SchematicPolygon", "Robinson"}] /. Polygon[{p__?MatrixQ}] :> Map[Polygon, {p}], Unevaluated[RandomColor[]], {1, -2, 2}], Background -> ColorData["Legacy", "Azure"]]` suit your needs?

Comment: @J.M. That still appears to have the anti-aliased borders between countries. I can maybe deal with those in an image editor but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: What if you use `"FullPolygon"` instead of `"SchematicPolygon"`? FWIW: these are all generating *vector* graphics, which you can easily resize before saving as an image file.

Comment: I still see the borders. Also the water and bg are the same color. (Thanks for helping btw :))

Comment: Then I don't know what "borders" you're seeing; contrast `Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Riffle[CountryData["World", {"FullPolygon", "Robinson"}] /. Polygon[{p__?MatrixQ}] :> Map[Polygon, {p}], Unevaluated[RandomColor[]], {1, -2, 2}]}, Background -> ColorData["Legacy", "Azure"]]` with the previous snippet. Also: can you tell me why the background and water can't be the same color? (Note that the polygons for countries do not have holes corresponding to lakes and other landlocked bodies of water.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `GeoGraphics`:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling@Opacity@1, RandomColor[], 
    CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"]} & /@ Join[CountryData["Continents"], CountryData[]], 
 GeoBackground -> Hue[0.56, .8, .8, .5], GeoRange -> "World", 
 GeoProjection -> "Robinson", Background -> White]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Just what I wanted. (Any chance of adding antarctica?)

Comment: Since Antarctica is not a country, it's not returned by `CountryData[]` (cf. [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3646/89)). I've joined continents and countries to have everything - make sure you do not change the order as then continents would cover countries.

Answer (score 3):

From its doc

```
Graphics[{Hue[
 2/3 Sqrt[
   1 - (CountryData[#, 
        "IndependenceYear"] /. {DateObject[{y_}] :> y, _Missing ->
          First[DateList[]]})/First[DateList[]]]], 
CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"]} & /@ CountryData[]]
```

which makes it plot countries color coded by the length of their claimed independence. You can plot by any other method.

Comment: This is almost just what I want :) but (unless I'm very mistaken), it's not a Robinson projection. How could I fix that?